# Accidentally removed iPhone from Finder sidebar in MacOS. How to restore?

Tags: macos, iphone, finder

I accidentally removed my iPhone from the Finder sidebar. How do I restore it? My iPhone always used to be displayed in the Finder even when it wasn't connected to my computer (MacBook Pro) with a cable, because it was set to backup wirelessly to the laptop.

I'd like to have the iPhone back in the Finder sidebar so I can save a backup. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Please explain "aaccidentally".

Comment: Can't you just connect it with a cable to have it re-appear?

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with this issue for some time, but found the solution: it is easy to do but unfortunately placed.

Open the Finder preferences, and go to "Sidebar".

[image: toggle the setting for iOS devices]

In here, you will notice that the setting "CD, DVDs and iOS Devices" has a small minus sign, which indicates that it is partially enabled. Click the checkbox, and it will turn into a checkmark.
Now, all iOS devices will be shown again.